# Want to create Neo4j Nodes relationships using APOC and foreign key constraint auto

Tags: neo4j, relationship, rdbms, neo4j-apoc

I have RDBMs tables with me (Consider just 2 tables having 1:M relationship), I want to create Neo4j Graph using APOC library call. I can fetch row and create nodes, But How I can create relationship? I don't want to create relationship manually by checking foreign key myself, I want it to get done automatically i.e it should understand what is foreign key and create relationship and give the name to relationship as name of foreign key constrain

Search for calls but didnt find any yet

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Consider ,
Student table
Name RollNo (pk)   Marks 
Amit     1                 45
Rahul     2                50

And Teacher table
Name     SRNo(fk from pk RollNO)  
Ashok     1
Ashok     2
Arun       1

This should create a graph with relation name as SRNO

Comment: It's not possible to create a relationship automatically, neither does the DB knows about the relation type, nor does it know how to infer the foreign key